# C library - iterative sparse complex linear equation solver?

Tags: linear-algebra

Where can I find a library to solve a sparse complex matrix equation iteratively in C.
So far I've only found libraries for direct solution to complex systems, and libraries for iterative solutions to real systems, but no solvers for iterative solutions to complex systems

Comment: Good answer by Bernardo, but I wanted to point out that [Jack Dongarra maintains a list of software for linear algebra problems](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/la-sw.html) that you might want to consult for future questions of this nature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PETSc (http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc)

But you have to build PETSc specifically for solving complex systems.

Have a look at installation instructions for complex version:
http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/installation.html